# Multiply each element of an array by a number in C

Tags: c, arrays, multiplication

I'm trying to optimize some of my code in C, which is a lot bigger than the snippet below. Coming from Python, I wonder whether you can simply multiply an entire array by a number like I do below.

Evidently, it does not work the way I do it below. Is there any other way that achieves the same thing, or do I have to step through the entire array as in the for loop?

```
void main()
{
    int i;
    float data[] = {1.,2.,3.,4.,5.};

    //this fails
    data *= 5.0;

    //this works
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) data[i] *= 5.0;

}
```

Comment: you have to traverse the complete array.. no other option

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no short-cut you have to step through each element of the array.

Note however that in your example, you may achieve a speedup by using `int` rather than `float` for both your data and multiplier.

Comment: thanks! yeah, my real data are floats. I was just to lazy to put that in here.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to, you can do what you want through [BLAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms), Basic Linear Algebra Subprograms, which is optimised. This is not in the C standard, it is a package which you have to install yourself.

Sample code to achieve what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cblas.h>
int main () {            
    int limit =10;
    float *a =  calloc( limit, sizeof(float));
    for ( int i = 0; i < limit ; i++){
        a[i] = i;
    }
    cblas_sscal( limit , 0.5f, a, 1); 

    for ( int i = 0; i < limit ; i++){
        printf("%3f, " , a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The names of the functions is not obvious, but reading the guidelines you might start to guess what *BLAS* functions does. `sscal()` can be split into `s` for *single precision* and `scal` for `scale`, which means that this function works on floats. The same function for *double precision* is called `dscal()`.

If you need to scale a vector with a constant and adding it to another, BLAS got a function for that too:

```
saxpy()
s      a x p y
float  a*x + y
y[i] += a*x
```

As you might guess there is a `daxpy()` too which works on `doubles`.

Comment: interesting! I'll look into it.

Comment: If you work on ubuntu I can add I had a problem when installing it, but the solution to that was:
`sudo aptitude install libblas-dev libopenblas-dev libopenblas-base`
`sudo ldconfig`

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that, in C, you will have to use `for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) data[i] *= 5.0;`.
Python allows for so many more "shortcuts"; however, in C, you have to access each element and then manipulate those values.

Using the for-loop would be the shortest way to accomplish what you're trying to do to the array.

EDIT: If you have a large amount of data, there are more efficient (in terms of running time) ways to multiply 5 to each value. Check out loop tiling, for example.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd recommend unrolling loops by hand.  Won't any half-decent compiler optimise your loops appropriately if you tell it to optimise for speed?

Comment: I know about loop unrolling and the -O flags, I'm still trying to optimize on top of that ;-).

Answer (score -3):

```
data *= 5.0;
```

Here ***data*** is address of array which is constant.
if you want to multiply the first value in that array then use * operator as below.

```
*data *= 5.0;
```

Comment: Did you mean `*=`?  Your code shows how to add 5 to the first element, not multiply it.